# Printing colored text in terminal from python command

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have this python script in which I run in terminal. Currently I am trying to incorporate colors, eg. if it is 'error', the text will be red, if it is 'working', the text will be green.

I have tried to refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) that I have found but when I tried to run it in my terminal using the following code:

```
print('\x1b[0;31;40m' + 'Error!' + '\x1b[0m')
```

I am getting red text with a greyish background instead of red text with black background.
My terminal uses Python 2.6.2.

My question here is:
1. Is there any way to get rid of this 'greyish' background?
2. Instead of setting colors to the background, is there an 'invisible' option? Eg. if I run the command, the printed text background will conform to the terminal background?

Comment: Would trying a package like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama be helpful for you?

Comment: `print('\x1b[31m' + 'Error!' + '\x1b[0m')` will print in red on the default background, unless you're using a custom palette. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Answer (score 3):

On a similar note, you can define colors and text decorators you want to use in a class and use them during printing instead of explicitly stating them in every print:

```
class Colors:
    Green, Red, White = '\033[92m', '\033[91m', '\033[0m'
    Bold, Italics = '\033[1m', '\x1B[3m'

print(Colors.Green + Colors.Bold + "I'm bold and green!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all terminals have the same color scheme as it's usually defined by the author. Some use black as background, others use dark grey. So your efforts may won't appear the same on other machines.

Moreover, be aware that text in standard red color isn't the same tone of red in all terminals, whether it's normal or bright. Sometimes with a little orange teint, sometimes a little darker. And the same goes for other standard colors.

Find an overview of various terminals and their color palettes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit).

But why code everything from scratch? Several Python packages can solve your problem. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package. [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) is lightweight and less verbose. Simply install the package with `pip install colorist` and refer to the [background color options](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/reference/background-colors/mixed/).

Other options for foreground colors:

```py
from colorist import red

red("some text in red color")
```

[image: some text in red color]

Sometimes you may want a little more control over the terminal style, so you can also do this:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"Only {Color.CYAN}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

[image: 5]